# Android to Django - always showing 401

Tags: android, django, apache, ssl, http-status-code-401

I am trying to connect to my Django backend server from my app. While in local/dev with http connection the android app is getting connected to the server, it is rreturning HTT 401 error for all API calls via the app (except the login call). However, funny thing is using Postman, I'm being able to reach the prod server.

Following is one of the code snippets (android):

```
try{
            URL targetUrl = new URL(targetURL);
            httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) targetUrl.openConnection();
            httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "jwt " + mToken);
            httpConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000); //10secs
            httpConnection.connect();

            Log.i(TAG, "response code:" + httpConnection.getResponseCode());
            if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() != 200){
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed : HTTP error code : " + httpConnection.getResponseCode());
                return Constants.Status.ERR_INVALID;
            }

            //Received Response
            InputStream is = httpConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            String line;
            while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
                //response.append('\r');
            }
            rd.close();

            Log.i(TAG, response.toString());
            // Save the tenant details
            return parseTenantInfo(response.toString());

        }catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return Constants.Status.ERR_NETWORK;

        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return Constants.Status.ERR_NETWORK;
        }

        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return Constants.Status.ERR_UNKNOWN;
        }finally {

            if(httpConnection != null) {
                httpConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }
```

Following is the target url:

```
private static final String targetURL = Constants.SERVER_ADDR + APIs.tenant_get;
```

Here, SERVER_ADDR is https://www.example.com/ and tenant_get is apitogettenantinfo/

I am always getting 401 error. Kindly help me out!!! Thanks.

The most irritating thing is Postman works, android login works. So it is seemingly no issue with server (else how would postman work?). And I can't understand what the android issue is.

EDIT:

Following is the screenshot of my postman. A few things are blacked out for security & privacy:

http://imageshack.com/a/img923/231/wUrOuS.png

Comment: Look this [https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10.4.2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10.4.2) .

Comment: what's the value of `mToken`? is it same as in postman?

Comment: The request requires user authentication. The response MUST include a WWW-Authenticate header field (section 14.47) containing a challenge applicable to the requested resource. The client MAY repeat the request with a suitable Authorization header field (section 14.8).

Comment: Yes. The value of mToken is the same as Postman. @KeLiuyue, I have included authorization as can be seen in the code snippet and this exact thing is working with Postman. Not sure what's the error

Comment: Show the PostMan screenshot .

Comment: @KeLiuyue I have updated with a screenshot for your info

Comment: Where do you get `mToken` ?

Comment: As sn as the user logs in (using username and password), they hit the db and the db sends the token, which is stored as mToken in sharedpreferenes.

Answer (score 0):

401 indicates unauthorised request, make sure you are sending correct token.

Also remove `httpConnection.connect();`